# code inside $(document).ready() isnt ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, module, scope, mustache

feeling bad after hours of searching
trying to refactoring one of my old modules on a rendered Mustache template
Its like

```
<section id="slideShow">
    <script id="slideShow-template" type="text/template">
        <ul>
            {{#slideShow}}
            <li class="{{{class}}}">
                <img src="{{{img}}}" alt="{{{title}}}">
                <a href="{{{link}}}">
                    <h1 class="slideShowTitle">{{title}}</h1>
                    <p class="slideShowDate">{{date}}</p>
                    <p class="slideShowDetail">{{detail}}</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            {{/slideShow}}
        </ul>
        <nav>
            {{#slideShow}}
                <a href="javascript:;"></a>
            {{/slideShow}}
        </nav>
        <a href="javscript:void(0)" class="prevSlide"></a>
        <a href="javscript:void(0)" class="nextSlide"></a>

    </script>
</section>
```

and js

```
(function() {

        var slideShow = {
            slideShow: [
                ...some data...
            ],

            init: function() {
                this.cacheDom();
                this.initPosition();
                this.bindEvents();
                this.render();
            },

            bindEvents: function() {
                this.$el.on('click', '.nextSlide', this.nextSlide.bind(this))
            },

            render: function() {
                var data = {
                    slideShow: this.slideShow
                };
                this.$el.html(Mustache.render(this.template, data));
            },

            cacheDom: function() {
                this.$el = $('#slideShow');
                this.$ul = this.$el.find('ul');
                this.$li = this.$ul.find('li');
                this.$nav = this.$el.find('nav');
                this.$a = this.$nav.find('a');
                this.$next = this.$el.find('.nextSlide');
                this.$prev = this.$el.find('.prevSlide');
                this.template = $('#slideShow-template').html();

            },

            initPosition: function() {
                 this.$ul.css('left', '0');
            },

            nextSlide: function() {
                alert('test OK');
            }

        };

        slideShow.init();

    })();
```

**the problem is the initPosition() function doesnt give the dynamic element the CSS style, I even wrapped the whole code in $(document).ready() but it still doesnt work
and Im trying to write this modular and clean, prefer to control the behavior inside of the module not outside, is there a way to achieve this in one line of code or function, everything except setTimeout ?**

I event tried

```
this.$el.on('ready', 'ul', somefunc(){....})
```

MOSTLY
I want to know what pros do in this situation, how they keep separation and keep their DOM refers in only one function and scope, is there any middle function for something like that or ...

I dont have a clue
please let me know what do I missing thanks

Comment: where are all these `$el, $ul` etc defined?

Comment: well elements do not have ready so that is not going to work. Did you make sure it is actually finding the elements?

Comment: no ,its not finding, Im trying to find a way the module find them after the dom become ready,

Comment: well HOW is the module being loaded?

Comment: It shows the data, Im sorry I dont fully undestand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered in chat:

The problem is that your init function leaves rendering till last, but the methods before it all expect the elements to be there.
The correct order for your init function would be:

```
init: function() {
  this.render();
  this.cacheDom();
  this.initPosition();
  this.bindEvents();
},
```

That way when cacheDom runs all the `this.$el.find` calls will actually find the elements.